# Binary-search + linear-search to find multiple matches. How to return a tuple of results? (Python)

Tags: python, search, binary-search

I've written a search algorithm that finds a string in a sorted list, and then searches the entries either side for duplicates.

```
import re

found = []
missing = []

def find_media(media, drive_inv):
    """
    media is a string.
    drive_inv is a list of strings.
    use binary search to find a match,
    followed by a linear seach either side
    to check for duplicates.
    append a match to the global list, found.
    else append to the global list, missing.
    """

    def linear_search_up(media, line):
        """ line is an int, to index drive_inv with. """

        try:
            if re.search(media, drive_inv[line+1], re.IGNORECASE):
                found.append(drive_inv[line+1])
                return linear_search_up(media, line+1)
            else:
                return 

        except IndexError:
            return 

    def linear_search_down(media, line):
        """ line is an int, to index drive_inv with. """
        try:
            if re.search(media, drive_inv[line-1], re.IGNORECASE):
                found.append(drive_inv[line-1])
                return linear_search_down(media, line-1)
            else:
                return 

        except IndexError:
            return 

    def binary_search(media, low, high):
        """
        low and high are ints - the boundries of the
        binary search algorithm.
        if a match is found, execute the linear seach
        function on the entries either side.
        """

        if high == low:
            if re.search(media, drive_inv[low], re.IGNORECASE):
                found.append(drive_inv[low])
                return
            else:
                missing.append(media)
                return

        mid = (low + high) / 2

        if re.search(media, drive_inv[mid], re.IGNORECASE):
            found.append(drive_inv[mid])

#           now check the entries either side
            return (
                    linear_search_up(media, mid),
                    linear_search_down(media, mid
            )

#       if the filename > media, discard the larger entries
        elif drive_inv[mid].split('/')[-1] > media:
            if low == mid:
                missing.append(media)
                return
            else:
                return binary_search(media, low, mid-1)

#       if the filename < media, discard the smaller entries
        else:
            return binary_search(media, mid+1, high)

    if len(drive_inv) == 0:
        return
    else:
        return binary_search(media, 0, len(drive_inv)-1)
```

It seems to work well, but it's a bit ugly, appending the results to global lists. I'd like for it to return a tuple of all the matches.  However, if I change:

```
found.append(drive_inv[line+1])
return linear_search_up(media, line+1)
```

to:

```
return (
        drive_inv[line+1],
        linear_search_up(media, line+1)
)
```

I end up with a tuple that looks like:

```
(('A001C002', ('A001C002', None)), ('A001C002', ('A001C002', ('A001C002', ('A001C002', None)))))
```

...which isn't much good.

Can this be rewritten and still use recursion? Or should I consider a different method?

Comment: Please show your actual result. The `return` statement you wrote above can never produce the result you posted.

Comment: I suppose you mean finds a string in an sorted list, since all lists are ordered.

Comment: Cheers, I've addressed both comments.

Comment: When I ran your code on this data, `drive_inv = ['A001C000', 'A001C000', 'A001C001', 'A001C002', 'A001C002', 'A001C002', 'A001C003', 'A001C003', 'A001C003', 'A001C004', 'A001C005']` and called `find_media('A001C002', drive_inv)` which returned `(None, None)` leaving the global `found` set to `['A001C002', 'A001C002', 'A001C002']` and the global `missing` set to `[]`. You said it works well, what exactly would you like the returned tuple value to be?

Comment: I'd like the tuple to return `('A001C002', 'A001C002', 'A001C002')`, and not to use a global list.  Originally, the algorithm was a class method, so appending to self.found was fine - but I'd rather it be a global function and share it with other classes. I don't feel it belongs to a particular class so I don't want to use composition/inheritance.

Comment: So what you want to determine is how many times the `media` string is in sorted `drive_inv` string list? If so, there are much simpler ways to determine that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's probably possible to modify your code to get it to do what you want, the same thing can be accomplished with the approach shown below — which is likely faster and doesn't require the list of strings to be sorted.

```
from collections import Counter

def find_media(media, drive_inv):
    cnt = Counter(drive_inv).get(media, 0)
    return (media,)*cnt if cnt else None

drive_inv = ['A001C000', 'A001C000', 'A001C001', 'A001C002', 'A001C002',
             'A001C002', 'A001C003', 'A001C003', 'A001C003', 'A001C004',
             'A001C005']

print find_media('A001C002', drive_inv) # -> ('A001C002', 'A001C002', 'A001C002')
print find_media('A001C099', drive_inv) # -> None
```

If you would like it to return an empty tuple when`media`isn't found instead of`None`, change the function's return statement to:

```
    return (media,)*cnt
```

Comment: @tedwood: One difference I should point out is that, unlike in your code, this approach is case-sensitive. If that's an issue, there are at least a couple of ways I can think of to make the strings used case-insensitive.